# Take random distribution of s in gamma(1, 1) and plot a transformation of x

Tags: python, gamma-distribution

Let x be a random variable with probability density function (pdf) x ~ Gamma(1, 1). How to plot the pdf of z where z=x^2/(1+sin(x))? This is what I have tried, I am not sure how to get z from x.

```
x = np.linspace (0, 100, 200) 
y1 = stats.gamma.pdf(x, a=1, loc=1) 
plt.plot(x, y1, "y-", label=(r'$\alpha=29, \beta=3$'))
```

Comment: What have you tried? Any guess on why it doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot gamma distribution with alpha and beta parameters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150965/how-to-plot-gamma-distribution-with-alpha-and-beta-parameters-in-python)

Comment: @JuanR please see my updated post. Thanks